# Clone a canvas rectangle with animation on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I want my code to generate a canvas rectangle upon clicking a button and move left until it reaches end of the page. But I am unable to clone the canvas. Here's what I've tried so far.

my.js
enter code here

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
      })();

      function drawRectangle(myRectangle, context) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);
        context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = myRectangle.borderWidth;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();
      }
      function animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime) {
        // update
        var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

        var linearSpeed = 100;
        // pixels / second
        var newX = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

        if(newX < canvas.width - myRectangle.width - myRectangle.borderWidth / 2) {
          myRectangle.x = newX;
        }

        // clear
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

        // request new frame
        requestAnimFrame(function() {
          animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
        });
      }
      var canvas   = document.createElement('canvas'); // create new canvas
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var myRectangle = {
        x: 0,
        y: 75,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        borderWidth: 5
      };

      drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

      // wait one second before starting animation
      setTimeout(function() {
        var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
      }, 1000);


$('#button').click(function() {
     var el = $("#canvas"),  
     newone = el.clone(true);
     el.before(newone);//This line is added just for styling
});

$('#button').click(function() {


      window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
      })();

      function drawRectangle(myRectangle, context) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);
        context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = myRectangle.borderWidth;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();
      }
      function animate(myRectangle, canvas1, context, startTime) {
        // update
        var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

        var linearSpeed = 100;
        // pixels / second
        var newX = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

        if(newX < canvas1.width - myRectangle.width - myRectangle.borderWidth / 2) {
          myRectangle.x = newX;
        }

        // clear
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas.height);

        drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

        // request new frame
        requestAnimFrame(function() {
          animate(myRectangle, canvas1, context, startTime);
        });
      }

      var canvas1   = document.createElement('canvas'); // create new canvas
document.body.appendChild(canvas1);
      var context = canvas1.getContext('2d');

      var myRectangle = {
        x: 0,
        y: 200,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        borderWidth: 5
      };

      drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

      // wait one second before starting animation
      setTimeout(function() {
        var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        animate(myRectangle, canvas1, context, startTime);
      }, 1000);


});


});
```

HTML page

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <br><br>
    <script src="my.js"></script>
    <button type="button" id="button">
    Create
    </button>
```

This code only creates a single rectangle and upon clicking a button no action is being performed.Please help

Comment: try http://fabricjs.com/